# How can server side rendering functions utilize DB calls?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js

Since they required data that is fetched **AFTER** build-time, how do I delay the execution of the mentioned functions until the data is received?

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // get the paths we want to pre render based on products
 
  const paths = products.map((product) => ({
    params: { slug: 
      product.slug }
  }));
console.log(paths,"Paths in getStaticPaths()")
  return { paths, fallback: false };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  // get product data based on slug

  const product = products.filter((single) => single.slug === params.slug)[0];
  console.log(product,"In getStaticProps()")
  return { props: { product } };
}
```

In the above, the `products` contains all the raw data that is imported.

I need to replace this import of data with an import of a function that returns the data, but I end up with null as the call is not dine yet.

Comment: Please elaborate your question with an example that is not working for you!

Comment: Currently locally stored data help generate the paths required.The data is now called from an external database which is only made available after a few seconds,by when the getStaticProps() and .....Paths() use a null datapoint as it is not yet populated with the database data.

Comment: Wouldn't something like this work??

```
// db.js
export const db = createDb(config);

// main.js
import { db } from './src/db/';

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = await db.readDocument('PATH');
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true or false // See the "fallback" section below
  };
}
```

Comment: Add code sample plz

Comment: Whats the difference between importing a variable that holds that is supposed to hold the data,and importing a class that has a function which when called returns the data?        As an aside,the database call is  asychronous that stores the database value in a singleton,which i then am trying to access.But since the above getStaticPaths() is executed before anything i get left with null insitead of data.   Wouldnt the same thing happen,or does the await(as in your code above)  prevent that?

Comment: Added code. @B.Mohammad

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `useEffect` hooks, in the first initiate the data and when ready set it in a state `data`,
in the second `useEffect` you can do something like:

```js
useEffect(()=>
 if(data){
   // setLoader(false)
}else{
 // setLoader(true)
},[data])
```

and in the return you do conditional rendering:

```js
if (loading){
 return(<ActivityIndicator/>)
}else{
 return // your component
}
```

Comment: This is a solution when calling the database api. How does getStaticProps and getStaticPaths know when it receives the data before it executes? Since they are not related to react-components, hooks or any such process cannot work.

Comment: redux can be used to connect components to normal js files.

Comment: Would'nt the "export async function" not be able to read data from the connect statement?

Comment: you can read store state directly without the `connect` function, you use `const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => true);
    const yourState = store.getState().yourState;
    unsubscribe();`

Comment: Wouldn't the redux store be unavailable during build time, while getStaticPaths () and getStaticProps () which are Next. Js methods, execute during build time?

Comment: I don't know about that, i use that method for React-native apps